# How to Handle successful pop up message "Provisioning Success" ok on Appium python script provisioning

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, appium, popupwindow, appium-android

Im trying to run the provision application from appium python script and mobile conenected on the machine where for given ssid and password is connected.After successful connection for AP, we get provisioning success ok comes . POP up screen is coming . Following is the code below.
But This Provisioning success button is clickable false in Appium Inspector.Tried xpath
driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH, value="//android.widget.TextView[@text='Provisioning Success']").click()

```py
def perform_provision(self):
        # Desired Capabilities
        desired_cap = {
            "platformName": "Android",
            "platformVersion": "11",
            "deviceName": "RZ8M71M2E9X",
            "appPackage": "com.innophase.provisioning",
            "appActivity": ".MainActivity",
            "automationName": "UiAutomator2",
            "noReset": "true",
            "appium:connect_timeout": 30
        }
        #Initialize the driver
        options = UiAutomator2Options().load_capabilities(desired_cap)
        driver = webdriver.Remote("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub", options=options)
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Launching BLE Provisioning app")
        time.sleep(10)
        print("Clicking on scan now !")
        driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH, value="/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[2]").click()
        time.sleep(10)
        driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH, value="//android.widget.TextView[@text='DualStack1']").click()
        print("Selecting the device")
        #time.sleep(10)
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        ssid=driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH, value="//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'DualStack2')]").click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH, value="//android.widget.EditText[@text='Password']").send_keys("InnoQA2023$")
        time.sleep(10)
        driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH, value="//android.widget.TextView[@text='Submit']").click()
        print("Provisioning done successfully")
        time.sleep(12)
driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH, value="//android.widget.TextView[@text='Provisioning Success']").click()
```

Seeing this error Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/admin1/Desktop/temp_soma/test-automation-master-iot/./test_cases/DualStack/Wifi_provision.py", line 144, in 
test.perform_provision()
File "/home/admin1/Desktop/temp_soma/test-automation-master-iot/./lib/BLE_Provisioning.py", line 48, in perform_provision
ssid=driver.find_element(by=AppiumBy.XPATH, value="//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'DualStack2')]").click()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/appium/webdriver/webdriver.py", line 381, in find_element
return self.execute(RemoteCommand.FIND_ELEMENT, {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/appium/webdriver/errorhandler.py", line 125, in check_response
raise exception_class(msg=message, stacktrace=format_stacktrace(stacktrace))
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:

Comment: Could anyone check this and help on this? 
Im using Appium 2.0.1 version